# Efficient memory management in R

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I have 6 GB memory in my machine (Windows 7 Pro 64 bit) and in R, I get

```
> memory.limit()
6141
```

Of course, when dealing with big data, memory allocation error occurs. So in order to make R to use virtual memory, I use

```
> memory.limit(50000)
```

Now, when running my script, I don't have memory allocation error any more, but R hogs all the memory in my computer so I can't use the machine until the script is finished. I wonder if there is a better way to make R manage memory of the machine. I think something it can do is to use virtual memory if it is using physical memory more than user specified. Is there any option like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the ff and bigmemory packages.  This uses functions that know about R objects to keep them on disk rather than letting the OS (which just knows about chunks of memory, but not what they represent).

Answer (score 5):

R doesn't manage the memory of the machine.  That is the responsibility of the operating system.  The only reason `memory.size` and `memory.limit` exist on Windows is because (from `help("Memory-limits")`):

```
 Under Windows, R imposes limits on the total memory allocation
 available to a single session as the OS provides no way to do so:
 see 'memory.size' and 'memory.limit'.
```

R objects also have to occupy contiguous space in RAM, so you can run into memory allocation issues with only a few large objects.  You could probably be more careful with the number/size of objects you create and avoid using so much memory.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a solution but a suggestion. Use memory efficient objects wherever possible: for instance, use a matrix instead of a data.frame.

Here an example

```
m = matrix(rnorm(1000), 2, 2)
d = as.data.frame(m)
object.size(m)
232 bytes
object.size(d)
808 bytes
```

Comment: This example seems to only highlight the very small fixed data allocation difference. Take the matrix to be `m = matrix(rnorm(1000), 20000, 10)` and the size differences between the objects become negligible. In fact checking this for some random `data.frame` I had in my workspace, the `matrix` version was 2 times larger. So I don't think this suggestion is useful for the problem at hand.

Comment: No. I disagree. Matrix are more efficient than data.frame. That is one reason why internally, a lot of R functions will coerce to matrices data that are in data frames. I mention clearly that my answer is just a suggestion a best practice if you want. For your second comment ( random data.frame smaller then matrix version) I think it is False.

Comment: This is what I see for a specific `data.frame` I have in my workspace. `object.size(as.data.frame(rec)): 11542192 bytes` and `object.size(as.matrix(rec)): 26516160 bytes`.

Comment: Here's a reproducible example: `d = data.frame(a = 1:100, b = "b")` - try checking the various object sizes. There is no way to store e.g. numbers and strings together in a `matrix` in a more efficient manner (both for memory and for speed) than in a `data.frame`. Your suggestion will only save a negligible amount of memory (literally about 600 bytes) for uniform type `data.frame`'s and will not work for anything else.

Comment: @eddi Please try to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158790/data-frame-or-matrix) to get my point about matrix efficiency comparing to a data.frame.

Comment: Oh, I get your point, it's just that your point is irrelevant for the problem at hand. Cheers :) edit: note that the OP is about *memory* efficiency