# R running very slowly after loading large datasets > 8GB

Tags: r, memory, import

I have been unable to work in R given how slow it is operating once my datasets are loaded. These datasets total around 8GB. I am running on a 8GB RAM and have adjusted `memory.limit` to exceed my RAM but nothing seems to be working. Also, I have used `fread` from the `data.table` package to read these files; simply because `read.table` would not run.

After seeing a similar post on the forum addressing the same issue, I have attempted to run `gctorture()`, but to no avail.

R is running so slowly that I cannot even check the length of the list of datasets I have uploaded, cannot `View` or do any basic operation once these datasets are uploaded.

I have tried uploading the datasets in 'pieces', so 1/3 of the total files over 3 times, which seemed to make things run more smoothly for the importing part, but has not changed anything with regards to how slow R runs after this.

Is there any way to get around this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: [Look at the ff and bigmemory packages.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15845950/680068)

Comment: Do you really need all the columns and all the rows, all the time? Maybe subset before loading into R? `mydata <- fread("cut -f1-4 myFile.txt")` ?

Comment: @zx8754 looking at the packages now, thanks for your input. And that's a good point.. in fact I could remove a couple columns, will try this out

Comment: So I've been looking at the ff package, and trying to upload the files using some of the functions in the package. I have been trying to use the `read.delim.ffdf` command, yet I always get the same error: "scan() expected 'a logical', got 'TRBC1*00(15).." I looked online and didn't find anything addressing this issue. Have you dealt with this error in the past?

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises because R loads the full dataset into the RAM which mostly brings the system to a halt when you try to `View` your data.

If it's a really huge dataset, first make sure the data contains only the most important columns and rows. Valid columns can be identified through the domain and world knowledge you have about the problem. You can also try to eliminate rows with missing values.

Once this is done, depending on your size of the data, you can try different approaches. One is through the use of packages like `bigmemory` and `ff`. `bigmemory` for example, creates a pointer object using which you can read the data from disk without loading it to the memory.

Another approach is through parallelism (implicit or explicit). `MapReduce` is another package which is very useful for handling big datasets.

For more information on these, check out [this](https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis) blog post on rpubs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes) old but gold post from SO.