# Making a CSV file into an RData file

Tags: r, csv, rdata

Please bear with an R newbie here. I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial published on the wonderful flowingdata.com site by using my own data to replace the .Rdata file included in the tutorial. The Rdata file, "unisexCnts.RData", contains unisex names and the number of times used for different years:

```
head(unisexCnts)
        1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 1947 1948 1949 1950 1951
Addison    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Alexis     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Ali        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Alva       0    0  312  273  274  263    0  273    0  255  235  195  222    0  195    0  193  225  204  196  177  156
Amari      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Angel      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
        1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 1971 1972 1973
Addison    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Alexis     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  190    0    0  325    0    0    0    0    0    0
Ali        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  243  219  214
Alva     177  132  159  178  145  138  131  119  119  119  127   97  107   97   83   76   83   90   84   81   58   68
Amari      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Angel      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1264    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1579 2145 2488    0    0
        1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
Addison    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  595  664
Alexis     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Ali        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  561  565  556  643  747  722    0  742    0    0
Alva      54   57   53   54   59   40   62    0   48    0   28    0   34    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   26
Amari      0    0    0    0    0    0   11    0    0    0    0    0   16    0   22    0   32    0    0    0    0    0
Angel   2561 2690 2779    0    0 3004 3108 3113 3187 2924 3100 3341 3229 3101 3532 3889 4066 4520    0    0    0    0
        1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012
Addison  778  889    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Alexis     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Ali        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Alva       0    0    0   19    0   14    0    0    0    0    0   24    0    0    0    0    0
Amari      0    0    0    0    0    0 1181 1397 1333 1299 1265 1550 1780    0    0    0    0
Angel      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

When I run it through the str() function I get the follwoing:

```
str(unisexCnts)
 num [1:121, 1:83] 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:121] "Addison" "Alexis" "Ali" "Alva" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:83] "1930" "1931" "1932" "1933" ...
```

My data is in a csv file ,called "boysnames.csv":

```
 ,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008
    Jack,764,831,840,935,1068,1151
    James,746,773,796,746,711,737
    Daniel,678,683,711,792,842,828
    Conor,610,639,709,726,776,857
```

I am trying to overwrite the unisexCnts.RData with the contents of my boysnames.csv. So to restructure and get my csv ready to be saved, I did:

Step1.

```
unisexCnts<-data <- read.csv("boysnames.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Step2.

```
unisexCnts<-as.matrix(unisexCnts)
```

Step3.

```
save(file="unisexCnts.RData")  ##save as Rdata file, overwriting the original unisexCnts.RData in the dir
```

However I get the following after steps 1 & 2 which doesn't match the structure of the original, any ideas/pointers?

```
> str(unisexCnts)
 chr [1:100, 1:7] "Jack" "James" "Daniel" "Conor" "Sean" "Adam" "Ryan" "Michael" "Harry" "Noah" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "" "2013" "2012" "2011" ...
```

Comment: save.image(file="unisexCnts.Rdata"), I think you missed .Rdata

Comment: It would be more appropriate to simply use `save` if you're only saving a single data set. `save.image` is for saving your current workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a .csv file you can specify the column that should become the row names of the uploaded data using the command "row.names"

I recreated your data quickly and uploaded it using the following code:

```
read.csv('test.csv', stringsAsFactors = F,head = T, row.names = 1)
```

This saves you having to do this work after uploading the data. This gives you the data structure you are looking for as well:

```
unisexCnts = read.csv('test.csv', stringsAsFactors = F,head = T, row.names = 1)
unisexCnts = as.matrix(unisexCnts)
str(unisexCnts)
int [1:4, 1:6] 764 746 678 610 831 773 683 639 840 796 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:4] "Jack" "James" "Dan" "Conor"
 ..$ : chr [1:6] "X2013" "X2012" "X2011" "X2010" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> However I get the following after steps 1 & 2 which doesn't match the
>   structure of the original, any ideas/pointers?

In the original `unisexCnts` the names are specified as row names. That's why the the first attribute is

```
  ..$ : chr [1:121] "Addison" "Alexis" "Ali" "Alva" ...
```

To replicate that in your example. You can set the names as rownames by specifying

`rownames(unisexCnts) <- ListorOrVectorofNamesHere`

This will make the output match.

The reason this line:

```
 chr [1:100, 1:7] "Jack" "James" "Daniel" "Conor" "Sean" "Adam" "Ryan" "Michael" "Harry" "Noah" ...
```

doens't match this line

```
 num [1:121, 1:83] 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 ...
```

is the same. You have the names included in the actual matrix itself. In a matrix you can only have data of the same [type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158790/data-frame-or-matrix) . By including character data in the matrix (the names) you are converting the whole matrix itself into character/strings.

**in summary**
remove the name vector from the matrix and use it as row names and the `str()` of your two objects will match.