# changing the order of values in y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the ggplot2 to make a histogram. But the height of columns didn't follow the proportion of values on y-axis. Also the order of the value on y-axis isn't correct.

```
#This is the code I used.
data1 <- matrix(c("1", "2", "3", "4304", "456", "30"), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(1:3, c("number_gRNA", "ncell")))

ggplot(data1, aes(number_gRNA, ncell)) + geom_col(width = 0.4, fill="#56B4E9", colour="black") + ggtitle("sgRNA distribution")
```

[image]

I hope the height of columns can follow the proportion with their values. Meanwhile, the values on the y-axis follow increasing order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reorder bars in geom\_bar ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2)

Comment: You're using characters, i.e. `"456"` instead of `456`. There's nothing telling `ggplot` to convert those to numbers, so it doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong order of y axis in ggplot barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081052/wrong-order-of-y-axis-in-ggplot-barplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I made 2 simple changes to make it work.

First of all, `ggplot()` wouldn't take a matrix, so I used `as_tibble()` to make it work.

But to your question, it's taking `number_gRNA` as a character, and just assuming it's categorical. So you need `as.numeric()` to make that happen.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- matrix(
  c("1", "2", "3", "4304", "456", "30"),
  nrow = 3,
  ncol = 2,
  dimnames = list(1:3, c("number_gRNA", "ncell"))
)
data1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(ncell = as.numeric(ncell)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(number_gRNA, ncell)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.4, fill = "#56B4E9", colour = "black") +
  ggtitle("sgRNA distribution")
```

Comment: Good catch on the real problem here!