# Make a response variable binary

Tags: r

I just started to work with R, because I need to do a Lasso regression.
To get familiar with the system, I created a very plain matrix with 10 variables and 80 observations each using:

```
testmatrix<-matrix(rnorm(800),80,10)
```

I want the 10th variable to be the binary response variable. I already named the 10th variable "responsible_var", and now I would like to transform it into values either 1 (for >1) or 0 (for <1). I used the ifelse function:

```
testmatrix$responsible_var <- ifelse(testmatrix$responsible_var>0, 1, 0)
```

But it keeps telling me:

```
Error in testmatrix$response_var : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You may have to use `testmatrix[,'response_var']` as `$` wont' work with matrix

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  use it where: left or right of the "<-" ?

Comment: In both, i.e. `testmatrix[, 'response_var'] <- ifelse(testmatrix[,'response_var] >0, 1, 0)`  Or you can use the numeric index, i.e. `testmatrix[,10] <- `

Comment: @Moritz: I do not know what package you plan to use for your Lasso, but isn't it better to have it anyways in data.frame instead of matrix? Use `testmatrix<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(800),80,10))` and then `testmatrix[,11] <- ifelse(testmatrix[,10]>0, 1, 0)` will work.

Comment: I tried the first aproach and what happened is that it adds either "+00" or "+01" to each observation of response_var

Comment: @Moritz I don't know if your comment is directed towards me.  I was just copy/pasting your code (changed only the `$` part

Comment: Dear Ruthger, it worked indeed. thx to both of you !

Comment: just one last question: what is technically the difference between a pure matrix and a data.frame(matrix)?

Comment: Everything in a matrix must be the same data type. In a data frame, everything in a column must be the same data type, but different columns can have different data types. See also [data frame or matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5158790/903061).