# Can an R matrix contain different datatypes? Does this hacked-up matrix-of-lists work?

Tags: r, list, matrix, types

I read these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159049/1175496

  > Matrices are for data of the same type.
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/29732279/1175496

  > Vectors (and so matrix) can accept only one type of data

If matrix can only accept one data type, why can I do this:

```
> m_list<-matrix(list('1',2,3,4),2,2)
> m_list
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  3   
[2,] 2    4
```

The console output looks like I am combining character and integer data types.
The console output looks similar to this matrix:

```
> m_vector<-matrix(1:4,2,2)
> m_vector
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   1    3   
[2,]   2    4
```

When I assign to m_list, it doesn't coerce the other values  (as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29732279/1175496 )

```
> m_list[2,2] <-'4'
> m_list
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  3 
[2,] 2    "4"
```

Comment: Yeah, the matrix here is still a vector with a single type/mode. Try `?vector` to see the types of vectors.

Comment: I think it's generally a good idea to keep matrices to one type (e.g. pure `numeric`). However, I would be interested in the effect that using matrices in that way (`list`) has on computational performance; although the strongest argument is probably that things don't get messy...

Comment: I would recommend reading `?matrix` and not SO if you want precise definitions.

Comment: **If you want a matrix with different datatypes, use a dataframe (/ data.table/ tibble)** (Don't hack up a matrix-of-lists like this, it will fail on any non-trivial operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short-Answer*: Matrices in R cannot contain different data types. All data have to or will be transformed into either logical, numerical, character **or list**.

Matrices always contain the same type. If input data to matrix() have different data types, they will automatically transformed into the same type. Thus, all data will be either logical, numerical, character **or list**. And here is your case, in your example all elements are being transformed into individual lists.

```
> myList <- list('1',2,3,4)
> myMatrix <- matrix( myList ,2,2)
> myMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  3   
[2,] 2    4 
> typeof(myMatrix)
"list"
```

If you want to transformed completely your data from a list, **you need to unlist the data.**

```
> myList <- list('1',2,3,4)
> myMatrix <- matrix( unlist(myList) ,2,2)
> myMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "4" 
> typeof(myMatrix)
"character"
```

Answer (score 7):

OK here is what I gather from replies so far:

**Question**

How can I have a matrix with different types?

**Answer**

You cannot; the elements are not different types; all (4) elements of this matrix are lists

```
all(
is.list(m_list[1,1]), 
is.list(m_list[2,1]), 
is.list(m_list[1,2]), 
is.list(m_list[2,2]))
#[1] TRUE
```

**Question**

But I constructed matrix like this: `matrix(list('1',2,3,4),2,2)`, how did this become a matrix of (4) *lists*, rather than a matrix of (4) *characters*, or even (4) *integers*?

**Answer**

I'm not sure. Even though the documentation says re: the first argument to matrix:

> Non-atomic classed R objects are coerced by as.vector and all
>   attributes discarded.

It seems these are identical

```
identical(as.vector(list('1',2,3,4)), list('1',2,3,4))
#[1] TRUE
```

**Question**

But I assign a character (`'4'`) to an element of `m_list`, how does that work?

```
m_list[2,2] <-'4'
```

**Answer**

It is "coerced", as if you did this:

```
m_list[2,2] <- as.list('4')
```

**Question**

If the elements in `m_list` are lists, is m_list equivalent to `matrix(c(list('1'),list(2),list(3),list(4)),2,2)`?

**Answer**

Yes, these are equivalent:

```
m_list  <- matrix(list('1',2,3,4),2,2)
m_list2 <- matrix(c(list('1'),list(2),list(3),list(4)),2,2)
identical(m_list, m_list2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Question**

So how can I retrieve the `typeof` the `'1'` hidden in `m_list[1,1]`?

**Answer**

At least two ways:

```
typeof(m_list[1,1][[1]])
#[1] "character"
```

...or, can directly do this *(thanks, Frank)* (since indexing has this ["is applied in turn to the list, the selected component, the selected component of that component, and so on"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169495/1175496) behavior)...

```
typeof(m_list[[1,1]])
#[1] "character"
```

**Question**

How can I tell the difference between these two

```
m1 <- matrix(c(list(1), list(2), list(3), list(4)), 2, 2)
m2 <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
```

**Answer**

If you are using RStudio,

- m1 is described as `List of 4`
- m2 is described as `int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4`

..or else, just use typeof(), which for vectors and matrices, identifies the type of their elements... *(thanks, Martin)*

```
typeof(m1)
#[1] "list"
typeof(m2)
#[1] "integer"
```

`class` can also help distinguish, but you must wrap the matrices in vectors first:

```
#Without c(...)
class(m1)
#[1] "matrix"
class(m2)
#[1] "matrix"
#With c(...)
class(c(m1))
#[1] "list"
class(c(m2))
#[1] "integer"
```

...you could tell a subtle difference in the console output; notice how the m2 (containing integers) right-aligns its elements (because numerics are usually right-aligned)...

```
m1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 1    3   
#[2,] 2    4   
m2
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: Nice research and answer. It's standard here to get rid of the line-starting `>` and `+` and comment out the output so it's easy to copy-paste the code and try it out. `typeof` isn't the best way to examine objects in R, I find; it's mostly about storage type, not R class/type. I'd suggest `class(c(m1))` etc.

Comment: Thanks Frank. In future I will avoid ">" so users can copy-paste. And I also got the sense `class` is more aligned to my question than `typeof` ; the latter is storage-related

Comment: Frank, I incorporated your comments in my edit -- but I'm still struggling to understand why `matrix(list('1',2,3,4),2,2) ` becomes a matrix where each *item* is a list? As if the list class were "distributed" to each of the elements in there?

Comment: Good question. Actually, each item is *not* a `list` there. `m = matrix(list('1',2,3,4),2,2); sapply(m, class)`. Compare with `mm = matrix(list(list('1'),list(2),list(3),list(4)),2,2); sapply(mm, class)`. Note that the latter is constructed with `list`, unlike your example which uses `c`. I think you were expecting `c(list(1), list(2))` to be like `list(list(1),list(2))`, but it's actually like `list(1,2)`.

Comment: Yikes, so it makes things more complicated than I thought. Oh well, I hope this could help someone who confused themselves like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Picking up the comments, verify yourself:

```
typeof(m_list)
typeof(m_list[2,2])
```

Comment: Also worth looking at `typeof(m_list[[2,2]])`