# Why does R coerce numeric data to character when combined?

Tags: r, types

In R, I have a dataframe comprising of character and numeric fields. When I `rbind` the `data.frame` with another table, the whole `data.frame` changes to `character`.

What is going on?

```
x <-  data.frame("hello",1,2,3)

str(x)

x <- rbind(x,c("hello",1,2,3) )

str(x)
```

I hope to find a way not to change data type very easily in my code.

Comment: Can't find an exact duplicate but the main point is that `character` plus `numeric`==`character`.

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352746/can-an-r-matrix-contain-different-datatypes-does-this-hacked-up-matrix-of-lists).

Comment: You might benefit from a careful reading of `?c`. This explains the reasons behind the data type coercion that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the problem appears to be that you are using `rbind` with a vector, rather than a data frame.  `rbind()` was intended to join together two data frames row-wise.  As a solution here, consider using `rbind` with a data frame as the second parameter, e.g.

```
x <-  data.frame("hello",1,2,3)
class(x$X1)
x <- rbind(x, data.frame("hello",1,2,3))
class(x$X1)

[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Also, `c("hello",1,2,3)` changes everything to class `"character"`.