# how to apply functions on data frame in r

Tags: r

How can i apply the following function `rt` on each and every value `l` in `df`.
 `x` and `y` have the following values.

```
 x<-9
 y<-1

rt<-function(x,y,l) min(x,max(0,l-y))

df
a   b   c
5   6   7
1   4   1
2   4   3
```

Comment: `rt(x, y, unlist(df))`? And are you sure you actually want `df` as a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`?

Comment: yes i want to have it as dataframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158790/data-frame-or-matrix

Comment: What is `x`, `y` and `l` in your `df`?

Comment: `l` are all values in `df`. `x<-9` and `y<1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably simplest if you'd like to stick with dataframes is to use `apply` with the `MARGIN` parameter set to `c(1,2)`, which makes it apply the function by both rows and columns (i.e., to every cell).

```
x <- 9
y <- 1

rt <- function(x, y, l) min(x, max(0, l-y))

df <- data.frame(a = c(5, 1, 2),
                 b = c(6, 4, 4),
                 c = c(7, 1, 3))

rt_df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, c(1,2), rt, x = x, y = y))
```