# Extract information from one matrix through another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, extract

I have 2 matrices, one is species x traits and the second one is site x species (presence/absence). I need a third matrix sites x traits and in each column, I will have more than one value (all the values for all species of one site). How can I do this? Extract information of one matrix through another matrix? I am just a beginner in R...

I transposed the site x species and `cbind` the 2 matrices, but the result was all columns in one matrix...

```
trait <- read.table("trait_matrix_final.txt", head=T, sep="\t", dec=',', row.names=1)
com   <- read.table("community_matrix2.txt",  head=T, sep="\t", dec=',', row.names=1)
comt  <- t(com)
new   <- cbind(trait, comt)
```

And I tried to multiply both matrices, but it is not possible because I have continuous and categorical data.

### EDIT:

Complementary comments: I have continuous (*eg. body size*) and categoricals variables (*a daily activity with the values: nocturnal, diurnal or both*). So, if I have 3 species in site 1, I want to obtain mean body size for these 3 species for site 1. For the categorical variable, if the 3 species have these values: species 1= nocturnal, species 2= nocturnal and species 3 =diurnal, the column will be something like that: nocturnal+diurnal or nocturnal.diurnal. My third matrix will have the same numbers of columns that in the 1st matrix (species x traits), but the traits are averaged across all species for the particular site.

Comment: Share your code...what have you tried until now??

Comment: Hey Akshay, I just edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very useful to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so SO community can help you in solving the problem.

### AFTER EDIT:

You should store the data in an object of class `matrix` only if all entries of that matrix are of the same class (e.g. all `numeric` or all `character`). Because your first matrix has both numeric and character values it is better to format it as a `data.frame`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158790/should-i-use-a-data-frame-or-a-matrix) for more info.

I will generate some data assuming you have **5 traits** per species, **20 species** per site, and **10 sites**:

```
n.traits <- 5
n.species <- 20
n.sites <- 10

traits.names <- paste ("trait", 1:n.traits, sep = "_")
species.names <- paste ("spec", 1:n.species, sep = "_")
sites.names <- paste ("site", 1:n.sites, sep = "_")


# species*traits matrix
set.seed (4)
mat1 <- as.data.frame (matrix (replicate (n = n.traits, rnorm (n = n.species)), nrow = n.species, ncol = n.traits, dimnames = list (species.names, traits.names)))
mat1
set.seed (89)
mat1[, 2] <- sample (x = c ("diurnal", "nocturnal"), size = nrow (mat1), replace = T)
mat1

# site*species matrix
set.seed (6)
mat2 <- matrix (replicate (n = n.species, rbinom (n = n.sites, size = 1, prob = 0.8)), nrow = n.sites, ncol = n.species, dimnames = list (sites.names, species.names))
mat2
```

Following `for` loop will average traits across species for each site:

```
# sites*traits matrix
mat3 <- as.data.frame (matrix (NA, nrow = n.sites, ncol = n.traits, dimnames = list (sites.names, traits.names)))

for (i in 1:n.sites){
  spec_per_site_boolean <- mat2[i, ] == 1
  mat1_subset <- mat1[spec_per_site_boolean, ]
  
  for (j in 1:n.traits){
    if (is.numeric (mat1_subset[,j]))
      mat3[i,j] <- mean (mat1_subset[,j])
    else 
        mat3[i,j] <- paste (sort (unique(mat1_subset[,j])), collapse = ".")
  }
}
mat3
```

Note that the third matrix has the same number of columns as the first one (e.g. `ncol (mat1) == ncol (mat3)`), but it doesn't have the same number of rows (e.g. `nrow (mat1) != nrow (mat3)`).

Comment: Thanks for the help Newbie_R! But it is not what I needed, maybe I didn't explain well. I edit my question...