# Combine apply function with lapply: calculate mean of groups in df

Tags: r, apply, lapply

From two dataframes with single expression values (rows) per sample (cols) of different groups, I want to calculate the mean and median per group.
My solution seems a bit verbose and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

## Data

```
# expression values
genes <- paste("gene",1:1000,sep="")
x <- list(
  A = sample(genes,300), 
  B = sample(genes,525), 
  C = sample(genes,440),
  D = sample(genes,350)
)

# expression dataframe
crete_exp_df <- function(gene_nr, sample_nr){
  df <- replicate(sample_nr, rnorm(gene_nr))
  rownames(df) <- paste("Gene", c(1:nrow(df)))
  colnames(df) <- paste("Sample", c(1:ncol(df)))
  return(df)
}

exp1 <- crete_exp_df(50, 20)
exp2 <- crete_exp_df(50, 20)

# sample annotation
san <- data.frame(
  id = colnames(exp1),
  group = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))
```

## Solution

```
# get ids of samples per group
ids_1 <- san %>% filter(group == 1) %>% pull(id)
ids_2 <- san %>% filter(group == 2) %>% pull(id)
ids_3 <- san %>% filter(group == 3) %>% pull(id)
ids_4 <- san %>% filter(group == 4) %>% pull(id)
id_list <- list(group1 = ids_1, group2 = ids_2, group3 = ids_3, group4 = ids_4)

# fct means df1
get_means_exp1 <- function(id){
  apply(exp1[, id], 1, mean, na.rm = T)
} 
# fct means df2
get_means_exp2 <- function(id){
  apply(exp2[, id], 1, mean, na.rm = T)
} 
# lapply on df1
list_means_exp1 <- lapply(id_list, get_means_exp1)
means_exp1 <- as.data.frame(list_means_exp1)
# lapply on df2
list_means_exp2 <- lapply(id_list, get_means_exp2)
means_exp2 <- as.data.frame(list_means_exp2)
```

I suppose this can be solved much more elegant. Specifically, how to get the ids per group and write a function that works for both df.
Looking forwards to learning from your solutions, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately we can't run your code as `df1` and `df2` are missing and your `san` dataset has no `id` column which could be `pull`ed. But overall your approach looks quite complicated and could probably be easier achieved using e.g. `group_by` + `summarise`.

Comment: Thanks stefan, I corrected the example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I worked with the data generation process you provided and came up with a more simple solution. I changed exp1 into a dataframe, brought it in tidy format (`pivot_longer()`), added the groups from the san dataframe and finally applied the simple `dplyr` syntax to summarise your data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(exp1) %>%
  rownames_to_column("Gene") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= 2:21, names_to = "id", values_to = "Values") %>%
  left_join(., san) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mean= mean(Values),
            median= median(Values))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(id)`
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   group     mean  median
#>   <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.0803   0.0568
#> 2     2 -0.0383  -0.0387
#> 3     3 -0.00929  0.0356
#> 4     4 -0.0840  -0.0306
```

Considering your comment, simply also group by gene and that gets you the expected output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(exp1) %>%
  rownames_to_column("Gene") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= 2:21, names_to = "id", values_to = "Values") %>%
  left_join(., san) %>%
  group_by(group, Gene) %>%
  summarise(mean= mean(Values),
            median= median(Values))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(id)`
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 200 × 4
#> # Groups:   group [4]
#>    group Gene       mean  median
#>    <int> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 Gene 1  -0.0642 -0.122 
#>  2     1 Gene 10  0.0151  0.563 
#>  3     1 Gene 11 -0.0585 -0.0367
#>  4     1 Gene 12 -0.978  -0.917 
#>  5     1 Gene 13 -1.01   -1.37  
#>  6     1 Gene 14  0.160  -0.394 
#>  7     1 Gene 15 -0.295  -0.689 
#>  8     1 Gene 16  0.774   0.729 
#>  9     1 Gene 17 -0.356  -0.336 
#> 10     1 Gene 18 -0.741  -0.103 
#> # … with 190 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the means&medinas per gene per group, not all genes combined

Comment: I added that to my answer, @SebastianHesse.

Comment: I knew there is a much easier way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Before using `apply(., 1, FUN)`, it's always wise to check, if there is a vectorized function available because they're much faster. For the arithmetic mean of the rows there is `base::rowMeans`. For the medians we can use `matrixStats::rowMedians`. For row means you could also use `matrixStats::rowMeans2`, which is slightly faster. It makes sense to use `vapply` here, it is similar to `lapply`, but conveniently yields a matrix and is fastest in the `*apply` family, because we can pre-allocate memory. (*Note:* I used `set.seed(42)` to create your data.)

So maybe you are looking for this:

```
vapply(id_list, \(x) rowMeans(exp1[, x]), numeric(dim(exp1)[1]))
#              group1       group2       group3      group4
# Gene 1  -1.35631700 -0.328620048  0.160795323 -0.01011904
# Gene 2   0.33985130  0.432482763 -0.169343033  0.13019294
# Gene 3   0.46623064  0.154045975  0.362607622  0.58710492
# Gene 4   0.17049403 -0.036744170 -0.056742305  1.10934764
# Gene 5  -0.15515465  0.237211068 -0.426415836 -0.50977736

vapply(id_list, \(x) matrixStats::rowMedians(exp1[, x], useNames=TRUE), numeric(dim(exp1)[1]))
#              group1      group2       group3        group4
# Gene 1  -1.22551737 -0.41642403  0.470862918 -1.782411e-01
# Gene 2   0.05680326  0.62277321 -0.512487033  3.943679e-01
# Gene 3   0.58009311 -0.10696651  0.149054062  9.345673e-01
# Gene 4   0.09852832  0.12774134 -0.573525823  1.046751e+00
# Gene 5  -0.44076823  0.11716389 -0.381682466 -8.480807e-01
```

Comment: using `dplyr` based solution would it be faster than you suggested solution? I'm just curious

Comment: @PesKchan Since you seem to be looking for a fast solution, I updated my answer using `vapply` which is faster. I doubt very much that the `dplyr` solution would be faster, it's doing a lot of data transformation before calculation. You could check using `microbenchmark::microbenchmark`.

Comment: thank you. I did now learn another way to doing mostly i use `dplyr` for large set of genes and patient cohort which indeed takes time

Comment: @PesKchan I see, I do similar research with matrices with tens of thousands of genes. You probably have a lot of gene count matrices that are purely numeric. You should avoid data frame or similar class for these data and use the `"matrix"` format, which is much more [memory efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159049/6574038). The `matrixStats` package really has plenty of useful functions for fast matrix calculations, also bioconductor uses it in the [`MatrixGenerics`](https://github.com/Bioconductor/MatrixGenerics) package.

Comment: I really don't play around from the defined data class because I don't understand what might go wrong unless I see answers like yours which explain what exactly is going on with the function and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional alternative which scales very well you could use `data.table`.

```r
### load data.table
library(data.table)

### convert data.frames to data.table
exp1 <- as.data.table(exp1)[,Genes:=rownames(exp1),]
san <- as.data.table(san)

### switch to long format
exp1 <- melt(exp1, id.vars = "Genes", variable.name = "id", value.name = "Expression")

### join based on sample id
exp1Join <- merge.data.table(exp1, san, by = "id")

### compute statistics of choice
exp1Join[,.(mean=mean(Expression), median=median(Expression)),by=.(group, Genes)]
```

Of course you can also do everything in a combined table if you want to collect all your data and perform computations based on the whole dataset (different experiments).

```r
exp1 <- as.data.table(exp1)[,`:=`(Genes=rownames(exp1), Experiment=1),]
exp2 <- as.data.table(exp2)[,`:=`(Genes=rownames(exp2), Experiment=2),]

exp1 <- melt(exp1, id.vars = c("Genes", "Experiment"), variable.name = "id", value.name = "Expression")
exp2 <- melt(exp2, id.vars = c("Genes", "Experiment"), variable.name = "id", value.name = "Expression")

### combine tables
expCombined <- rbindlist(l = list(exp1, exp2))
expCombined <- merge.data.table(expCombined, san, by = "id")

### compute the mean, median, sd and sample size for every combination of gene, group and experiment
expCombined[,.(mean=mean(Expression),
               median=median(Expression),
               sd=sd(Expression),
               N=.N),
            by=.(group, Genes, Experiment)]

#     group   Genes Experiment        mean      median        sd N
#  1:     1  Gene 1          1 -0.29234057 -0.24008726 0.6278528 5
#  2:     1  Gene 2          1 -0.74158796 -0.82441474 0.6289399 5
#  3:     1  Gene 3          1 -0.49293277 -0.30616603 1.1442834 5
#  4:     1  Gene 4          1 -0.33610311 -0.43948117 0.5331471 5
#  5:     1  Gene 5          1  0.68955333  0.60701836 0.9475727 5
# ---                                                             
#396:     4 Gene 46          2  1.17036249  1.17036249 0.4885201 2
#397:     4 Gene 47          2  0.64894986  0.64894986 0.1122624 2
#398:     4 Gene 48          2 -1.61083175 -1.61083175 0.6319153 2
#399:     4 Gene 49          2 -0.07673634 -0.07673634 0.7263174 2
#400:     4 Gene 50          2 -0.37240955 -0.37240955 0.8037523 2
```

Also just as comparison I included a small test just for exp1 based on the original post, the provided Tidyverse solution, and the `vapply` approach. Obviously benchmarks like this make more sense when data sets are large.

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq        max neval cld
   TidyWay 57902.546 61651.077 76529.3966 67526.432 79027.012 172911.906   100 a  
     DTWay  2159.780  2490.218  3225.3781  2592.081  2960.918  17196.365   100  b 
    OrgWay  7459.775  8249.155 10667.4395  9224.186 11740.072  27480.962   100   c
 VApplyWay    87.618   133.598   168.3478   146.398   189.990    782.736   100  b
```